# Floating point arrays storing garbage value despite input correctly given

Tags: c++, io, floating-point

I'm trying to solve a problem for which I'll have to store float's in 3 different array's, surprisingly the values being stored are all zeros, could you point out what's going wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



int main(){
 
   int n,m;
  cin>>n>>m;
 vector<float>prb(n+1,0),prft(n+1,0),loss(n+1,0);
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    float x;
    cin>>x;
    prb.push_back(x);
  }
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    float x;
    cin>>x;
    prft.push_back(x);
  }
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    float x;
    cin>>x;
    loss.push_back(x);
  }
  
  cout<<endl;
  
   for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++){
    cout<<prb[i]<<' ';
  }
  cout<<endl;
   for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++){
    cout<<prft[i]<<' ';
  }
  cout<<endl;
   for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++){
    cout<<loss[i]<<' ';
  }
 
 
 
 
  
return 0;
}
```

Input :

```
4 2  
0.50 0.50 0.50 0.50  
4.00 1.00 2.00 3.00  
4.00 0.50 1.00 1.00
```

Output :

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Edit : arrays changed into vectors of floats. Still not getting desired values into them. Guys do you think the problem is with compiler or am I doing something stupid with c++.

Comment: `typedef unsigned long long int ull;typedef long long int ll;` -- There is absolutely no need for these crazy macros.  C++ has `int64_t`, `uint64_t`.  Second, this: `float prb[n+1];` and lines that look like this are not valid C++.  This looks like you're learning C++ from those "competitive programming" sites.

Comment: Indeed, but anyway It makes my life easier. How come? The deceleration looks fine to me?

Comment: Your code bears many marks of being used for so-called "competition" sites. All such sites teach are really bad habits that you shouldn't use (and if you use any of them in a job interview, you very likely won't be employed). Including one (variable-length arrays) that makes your code invalid in standard C++.

Comment: The point is that others here are looking at your code.  By obfuscating it with these nutty macros makes it harder for others to follow what you're doing.  Second, C++ starts array indices from `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Alright let me correct it, Apologies for inconvenience

Comment: Guys can we please have the problem be solved! Please

Comment: Cannot reproduce: [**Test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68a217b6e93a6466) (Please, note the warnings of g++ concerning the non-C++-standard [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s.)

Comment: Get rid of the non-standard variable-length arrays, and use `std::vector<float>` instead.  Those VLA's have been known to be broken for various versions of the compiler.

Comment: ...and cannot reproduce when VLAs replaced by `std::vector<float>`: [**Test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6de31e4bc8932a83) ;-)

Comment: Several fixes have been made to the VLA syntax so as to be usable for C++ container usage.  Better to not use them at all.

Comment: @PawanNirpal -- Now you've created a different problem.  You are now sizing your vectors on construction, but then you are calling `push_back` making the vectors even larger in size.  Now you see why competitive programming sites are worthless in learning how to write C++ code properly.

Comment: Have a look on [**Test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6de31e4bc8932a83) how to do it right with `std::vector<float>`. (The necessary changes are even less to what you had before.)

Comment: @Scheff I did get the expected output, how come this is not standard on all machines?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I couldn't agree more, cp isn't a great way to learn c++ or any language for that matter, but instead it's a great way of building problem solving skills. And c++ happens to be a convient yet fast enough apart from c, which is painful when it comes to cp.

Comment: As the program is currently in [**Test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6de31e4bc8932a83), this should be the expected output on all machines. If you got something different then a bug slipped in you are not aware of or the machine (or its local compiler) is simply broken. ;-) (Of course, I could've overseen something as well but I'm not aware of this...)

Comment: Concerning _it's a great way of building problem solving skills._ I don't agree. I believe it's a great way of building _cp_ problem solving skills. I cannot remember that I ever saw a cp task where I thought "Hey, that's exactly like what I once had in real business." I believe that cp is somehow popular today, seems to evolve its own culture, and some people enjoy to waste their time with it while others waste it with chilling, watching TV or YouTube clips or even doing some kind of sport in the outside. (I admit the last option is scaring somehow...) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff wow that's fascinating view you've got about, cp, with all due respect I completely disagree that cp is a waste of time, well a lot of folks do it for interviews mainly but unless you've tried it accusing it to be useless would be naive at best. It's more than just solving random problems that cp sites have, if you've ever done cp, it allows you to think in a very structured and precise sort of a way, and within today's distracted world that's a remarkably valuable skill to have. Also it's far more than just about interviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
vector<float>prb(n+1,0),prft(n+1,0),loss(n+1,0);
```

Can be replaced with,

```
vector<float>prb(n),prft(n),loss(n);
```

In your original program to fix it :)

Also, while accessing the values (precisely cout), access the i-1 th element instead of i th. Since, the default indexing done is 0-based, and you are accessing from index 1.

Like, prb[i-1], prft[i-1] and loss[i-1].

Comment: This worked, I feel so dumb for not having to realize such a simple way of doing this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The values being stored are not zeros, it's just that you initialise your vectors with a given size, with those values set to zero.

`push_back` appends new elements to the end of the vector.

Using `at` instead of `push_back` is the fix.

Comment: Thanks for the effort , but I'm still getting the same zeros.

Answer (score 0):

It is working ,just check this sample code ,and give input floating numbers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<float> v1;
    float x;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      cin>>x;
      v1.push_back(x);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) {
        cout << v1[i] << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```